# while inside of another while in PHP using MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I need to do the following - get the list of all artists from the database and print them on a page. But besides of that, I need to make another query to the "albums" table and get the albums of each artist and print the images under each artist description. The code I've written is as follows:

```
require('db.php');

$query = "SELECT * FROM artists";
$result = mysql_query($query);

$artist_id = $result[id];
$artist_name = $result[name];
$artist_surname = $result[surname];
$artist_email = $result[email];
$artist_about = $result[about];
$artist_photo = $result[photo];
while(list($artist_id, $artist_name, $artist_surname, $artist_email, $artist_about, $artist_photo) = mysql_fetch_row($result)) :
    print "<div class='row'>";
    print "<div class='artists_left'>";  
    print  "<div class='gallery_cont'><a href='#'><img src='timthumb.php?src=images/artists/$artist_photo&w=240&h=318' alt='$artist_name' /></a></div>";
    print  "</div>";  
    print "<div class='artists_right'>";
    print   "<div class='artist_title_cont'><span class='model'>Художник:</span><span class='name'>$artist_name $artist_surname</span><span class='mypage'>Личная почта:</span><a href='#' class='mypage'>$artist_email</a></div>";
    print   "<div class='artist_title_cont' style='margin-top:20px;'><span class='name'>$artist_about</span></div>";
    print     "<ul class='artists'>";
    $albums_query = "SELECT id, title_photo, dirname FROM albums WHERE master = $artist_id";
    $albums_result = mysql_query($albums_query);
    $album_id = $albums_result[id];
    $album_photo = $albums_result[title_photo];
    $album_dirname = $albums_result[dirname];
    while(list($album_id, $album_photo, $album_dirname) = mysql_fetch_row($result)) :   
        print "<li><a href='#'><img src='galleries/$album_dirname/$album_photo' alt='image' /></a></li>";
    endwhile;
    print "</ul>";
    print      "<a href='#' class='seemore_portfolio'>все работы мастера &gt;</a>";
    print  "</div>";    
    print "</div>";
endwhile;
mysql_close($connect);
```

The outer query works fine, but the inner one - does not. Could anybody help me to figure this out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you get any error from the second sql query?

Comment: What "does not" work about it? Are you getting errors, does nothing happen, do you get the wrong results? And why don't you use a `join` to select the image data on beforehand, instead of querying for each album?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the second `$result` to `$albums_result`

You can also consider writing the whole thing like this...

```
<? 
        require('db.php');

        $query = "SELECT * FROM artists";
        $result = mysql_query($query);

        while(list($artist_id, $artist_name, $artist_surname, $artist_email, $artist_about, $artist_photo) = mysql_fetch_row($result))
        {

        $li = '';

        $albums_query = "SELECT id, title_photo, dirname FROM albums WHERE master = $artist_id";
        $albums_result = mysql_query($albums_query);

        while(list($album_id, $album_photo, $album_dirname) = mysql_fetch_row($albums_result))
        {
            $li .= "<li><a href='#'><img src='galleries/$album_dirname/$album_photo' alt='image' /></a></li>";
        }

        echo "<div class='row'>
        <div class='artists_left'>  
        <div class='gallery_cont'><a href='#'><img src='timthumb.php?src=images/artists/$artist_photo&w=240&h=318' alt='$artist_name' /></a></div>
        </div>  
        <div class='artists_right'>
        <div class='artist_title_cont'><span class='model'>Художник:</span><span class='name'>$artist_name $artist_surname</span><span class='mypage'>Личная почта:</span><a href='#' class='mypage'>$artist_email</a></div>
        <div class='artist_title_cont' style='margin-top:20px;'><span class='name'>$artist_about</span></div>
        <ul class='artists'>
        $li
        </ul>
        <a href='#' class='seemore_portfolio'>все работы мастера &gt;</a>
        </div>
        </div>";

        }
```

Comment: Also.. fyi, the whole 6 line chunk of code where you assign $artist_id = $result[id], etc, etc..  is unnecessary. $result[id] doesn't exist and the subsequent list() just replaces all the values anyway